# How can I disable range requests ("Accept-Ranges: bytes") on IIS7?

Tags: iis-7

Is there a way to tell IIS to emit the header `"Accept-Ranges: none"` instead of `"Accept-Ranges: bytes"`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://forums.iis.net/p/1161071/1923541.aspx), it is not possible to disable byte-range processing (therefore the Accept-Ranges header) in IIS using the standard handlers.

If you were to develop a custom handler, you could of course disable the header.